# PHP Extensions "pdo_mysql" must be loaded

Tags: php, magento, ubuntu-16.04, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I'm installing Magento 1.x (2014 build), to Apache running PHP 5.6, MYSQL (latest).

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to complete the install `PHP Extensions "pdo_mysql" must be loaded.`

I've added (the line below, to the end of files):

`extension=pdo_mysql.so`

to both `php.ini` files:

`/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`

`/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini`

restart apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

I'm still receiving the error:

PHP Extensions "pdo_mysql" must be loaded.

This is on the "Configuration" page of the Magento install.

I've added (to the end of files):

extension=pdo_mysql.so

to both `php.ini` files:
/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini 
/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini

restart apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

I'm still receiving the error:

PHP Extensions "pdo_mysql" must be loaded.

Comment: Is it installed ? (sudo apt-get install php-mysql)

Comment: Yes.  From what I have read I need to compile into PHP

Comment: Do a $ php -m. Do you see pdo_mysql in the list of modules ?

Comment: I have PDO errors

` php -m | grep -i pdo`
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
sudo phpenmod curl
```

and restart apache